# How to creat a bump-map from a image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I need to make bump-map for objects like shirts or sofa that I could apply new patterns to it so how should convert the following shirt

[image]

into this:

[image]

?
How can I make bump-map for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop has a great filter doing the job called **displacement**
here you can find a pretty good tutorial how to apply any design on any "folds" 
please follow the [link](http://layersmagazine.com/displacement-maps-for-graphics-in-photoshop-cs4.html)

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks,But I don't want to use photoshop to apply patterns.I need to make a template which allow me to add patterns to it.I have searched and I find out that I need to create bump map for that.

Answer (score 0):

The images that you show give an example of the exact opposite of what you're asking for. Its easy to apply a pattern or color onto a photo of a blank peace of cloth, but very complicated to remove it. I'd say its defenitely not worth the effort. Also because i can't see any reason why you would have to use that exact shirt.

I recommend mockups. You can find them all over the web (mostly free)
like here for example:

[T-Shirt Mockups](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/articles/15-free-psd-templates-mockup-t-shirt-designs)

or here

[Mockup Selection on Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/harlowss/mockups/)

Of course, a mockup for a **Couch** is a rather rare thing amongst the web, but for that i'd recommend just a photograph of a blank white couch [like these](http://deutsch.istockphoto.com/search/text/white+couch/filetypes/photos,illustrations,video#d802dc5) and then apply your design or whatever you need to be on the cloth.

Hope that helps. Sry for bad english.

Comment: thanks.Actually I'm trying to make a stimulator for cloth and sofa.Let's make it more simple.I need to make bump map to apply different patterns to a sofa.Do you know anyway to make bump map for a sofa or cloth?

Comment: i dont think its possible to make something like a template for all kinds of shapes. you will have to do it for every single picture. therefore i'd just use a picture of bumps und whitecloth and then apply that to your picture with blending mode like multiplay or darker color.

Comment: Thanks,Let's assume that I have a white cloth .To apply patterns to it I need to make a bump map for that to be able to apply pattern using HTML.DO you know how to make a bump map for that?