# Photoshop: how to clean up edges from overlaid image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing

How can I clean up the edges of the square photo on top of this t-shirt?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the edges of the clouds on the image at the bottom?

Comment: I'm sure there's a displacement map answer here somewhere...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to creat a bump-map from a image](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42929/how-to-creat-a-bump-map-from-a-image)

Comment: From a design standpoint, consider removing something: this is way too busy and unfocused. Also, seriously consider that the Virgin Mary may appear to be popping out the person's pants. This may not be as you intended.

Answer (score 1):

To clean up the corners of a multiplied layer, use the 'Eraser' tool with a big, soft brush and gradually clean up the edges until they start to fade away. If the comp is not using layers it's more tricky, but still possible with a combination of 'Healing Brush' and/or 'Clone Stamp' tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate layers, I would recommend using a layer mask on that layers and using brushes (basic or textured) to mask part of it (paint with black on the mask).. Like so you can "unmask" (paint with white on the mask) and make modification to your mask easily instead of 'erasing" (destructive) parts of the real image.
Make sure you have a low "hardness" on the brush and use s big brush to avoid visible edges.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the image is on a separate layer above the t-shirt image and then go to the  layers palette. Top left where it says 'normal' change this to 'multiply' and toy a little with the opacity setting too. It ought to blend then with the shading in the fabric.